# Ubuntu version changed from official distribution to Kylin version

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I have a problem with a sudden change of Ubuntu system version: I installed the official Ubuntu 18.04 distribution, then I cleaned some junk files with Ubuntu Cleaner software, then the boot screen of my system changed from the original purple screen to the blue screen, and the boot screen prompted the boot system to change from Ubuntu to Kylin What happened is that I went into the system and the release screen was the same as before, but I checked my system version with "lsb_release -a" and the release changed to Kylin. What can I do to make it look like the old official Ubuntu distribution?

[image]

[image]

I tried switching the Ubuntu kernel version, but when I go to the advanced options from the boot screen, all the options in the distribution have the word "Kylin" in front of them, and after switching the kernel version the system version still says "Kylin". I then tried to repair the boot via Ubuntu's USB boot media, but it still didn't work and didn't change back to the previous version. What should I do to change my system version back to the previous version of ubuntu instead of "Kylin", because now I can't install software via PPA?

[image]

Comment: Suddenly switching distros isn't really a thing! You should probably do a completely fresh install. Keep your `/home` and start over.

Comment: Support for Ubuntu 18.04 ends in 3 days. Switch to a current version

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have installed
[Ubuntu Kylin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Kylin),
which is the official Chinese version of the Ubuntu computer
operating system.

If you're located in China, this confusion might not be accidental.

You could download and install the original version from
[ubuntu.com](https://ubuntu.com/).
Be sure to verify that the IP of the site is `185.125.190.20`
(which is what I get as the IP).

Comment: And DON'T install 18.04 which will be out of support in DAYS!

Comment: Thank you, I'm pretty sure I went to the Ubuntu website to get 18.04 instead of Ubuntu Kylin in the first place, and so far the issue hasn't really affected my usage, except for the fact that it doesn't work with the system when adding PPA. I'll follow the advice of others above and reinstall a new version of ubuntu later.